# Installing an SSL Certificate on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, certificate

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 Server with LAMP and Webmin configured. I have a name-based virtual host "mydomain.com" that is running fine and accepts connections via http:// or on port 80.

I want to enable SSL with a certificate I purchased from GoDaddy. I've read that others have an "SSL Options" button in their virtual host and can simply copy/paste the contents of their certificate in there. I don't have the button -- is there something I'm missing? Is there another way to do this with virtual hosts + Webmin?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the instruction on this [Howto to configure SSL](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/httpd.html). Scroll down to the HTTP Configuration section. You would need `mod_ssl` too.

> The directories /etc/ssl/certs and /etc/ssl/private are the default locations. If you install the certificate and key in another directory make sure to change SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile appropriately.